# 'int' is not iterable with if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I am working on a tic-tac-toe game and I am creating the if statements for the locations on the grid (i.e. (a,1) (b,2) (c,3) ect.)

I keep getting "'int' object is not iterable" once the code reaches my first if statement.

Current code:

```
def getXandY():
    y=input("Enter your move [letter, number]: ")
    acc=[]
    for i in y:
        acc.append(i)

    y=int(acc[1])
    x=acc[0]
    print(x,y)


    if y == 1:
        return 0
    print(x,y)
    if y == 2:
        return 1
    print(x,y)
    if y == 3:
        return 2
   else:
        return -1
    x=x.lower()


    num=convrtLet2Num(x)

    return num,y

def convrtLet2Num(x):
    if x == 'a':
        return 0
    if x== 'b':
        return 1
    if x== 'c':
    return 2
    else:
        return -1
```

I reaches the point where the first "print(x,y)" is and then the error happens at the if statement. Any ideas whats causing the error?

In the case I was testing y=1 and x='a'

Comment: What line of code is this on, and what version of python are you using? I ran this on python2.7, and there were no errors raised apart from indentation...

Comment: In python 2.7, `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`; if you enter a string like "[1, 2, 3]" it returns a list of integers.

Comment: @aj8uppal I am using 3.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
def get_move():
    while True:
        xy = input("Enter your move (ie b2): ").strip().lower()
        if len(xy) == 2:
            x, y = xy
            if x in "abc" and y in "123":
                return (ord(x) - ord("a"), ord(y) - ord("1"))
```

which runs like

```
>>> get_move()
Enter your move (ie b2): c2
(2, 1)

>>> get_move()
Enter your move (ie b2): a1
(0, 0)
```

Comment: Okay so I figured that part out with what you posted but I'm still getting the same error("x, y = getXandY() TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable")

Here is the whole code: http://pastebin.com/EDWRNXbd

Answer (score 2):

I think you are actually hitting the error earlier (it will help us if you include the error stack in your question) when you are doing:

```
for i in y:
     acc.append(i)
```

If you are expecting the user to input a list as a string n the format `[letter, number]`, you need to use `ast` modules' [`literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) method

Like this:

```
y=input("Enter your move [letter, number]: ")
acc=[]
for i in ast.literal_eval(y):
    acc.append(i)
```

So, when the user inputs this at the prompt:

```
Enter your move [letter, number]: ['a', 3]
```

the `ast.literal_eval(y)` will convert the input to the python list `['a', 3]`.

The following code prints the values of x and y correctly:

```
import ast
y=input("Enter your move [letter, number]: ")
acc=[]
for i in ast.literal_eval(y):
    acc.append(i)
y=int(acc[1])
x=acc[0]
print(x,y)
```

Demo:

```
$ python3 so.py
Enter your move [letter, number]: ['a', 1]
a 1
```

---

If however, you expect the user to enter a string in the format `letter number` without the square brackets, your code still will not do what you are expecting it to. Because `y` will have the string `a 3` (if the input is 'a 3'). And doing a

```
for i in y:
     acc.append(i)
```

will make `acc` a list of three elements `['a', ' ', '3']`. `y[1]` is now a space character. So this line in your code `y=int(acc[1])` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
def getXandY():
    y=raw_input("Enter your move [letter, number]: ")
    input_list = y.split(',')
    acc=[]
    for i in input_list:
        acc.append(i)
```

i assume the input is like: `a,1`
you can just modify the part I mentioned above, it will receive your letter and number input well with `raw_input`, and split it by comma..
it works fine in my computer. hope it helps..